# CQRS + clean architecture - common base type for commands

Tags: .net, architecture, cqrs, clean-architecture

Lets consider situation where we have:

- AddClientCommand
- UpdateClientCommand

Obviously they have base interfaces like IAddCommand and IUpdateCommand but it's not important in this case.

Anyway these two commands definitely have several common fields like name, address, age.  What if we create ClientBaseCommand and pull those common fields up there?  Then AddClientCommand & UpdateCLientCommand can inherit from that ClientBaseCommand.

Is this a good idea? Is it consistent with CQRS approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything inherently inconsistent between doing that and CQRS, but at the same time, I'm not sure it's likely to buy you much.

This would really only benefit you to the extent that your command handler has cases where it would treat the add and update commands in the same way.  I tend to find when doing CQRS that that's really only the case when the command-handler is effectively a finite state machine and there are states where certain commands are illegal.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously they have base interfaces like IAddCommand and
> IUpdateCommand but it's not important in this case.

Why would you want to have interfaces like the ones mentioned above on command objects? Perhaps an ICommand would be a good idea as a marker interface, but I don't see the value of adding an interface like IAddCommand.

I would not add a ClientBaseCommand because inheritance is so overused. Better to keep them apart in this case. code duplication can actually be a good in cases like this.

An alternative is perhaps to have a CommandBase class with generic command specific fields, like Id, CorrelationID, ClientId, ClientIP or similar cross-cutting concerns.

Comment: IAddCommand and IUpdateCommande as like you said marker interfaces but also I have BaseAddCommandHandler and BaseUpdateCommandHandler. These two base handlers contain diffrent logic for handling adding(IAddCommand) or updating(IUpdateCommand) records.

Comment: I don't see the need to separate Add from Update. in CQRS terms those are the same. Both wants to make changes to the system. Keep the commands plain data objects with no logic, I think is the best approach. See my code at https://www.cqrs.nu